# Can not select distinct on my table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I select only the distinct callers from my database where some calls are not answered?
For example: In this sample table i would like to select only the numbers 6666666 (at 2014-09-08 10:48:52)  and 5555555 (at 2014-09-08 11:52:10) because they where not answered by none extension.
I Tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from cdr WHERE disposition !='ANSWERED';
```

But this returns everything who not have the string 'ANSWERED' in disposition.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!!
Table Sample:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKZsh.png]

Comment: You can only use `distinct` on one column, you can't use it on `*`.

Comment: @the_pete That isn't accurate. `DISTINCT` applies across the entire `WHERE`-filtered row set, not the column whose name it appears near

Comment: Have you tried anything besides distinct (which won't really get you what you're looking for, btw)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date, src
from cdr
group by date, src
having sum(disposition = 'ANSWERED') = 0
```

in response to comment, if you need the other columns I suggest joining to the result above. Otherwise mysql will return a random value from each group for the columns that are not part of the group by. i.e.

```
select cdr.* from cdr join (
    select date, src
    from cdr
    group by date, src
    having sum(disposition = 'ANSWERED') = 0
) t1 on t1.date = cdr.date and t1.src = cdr.src
```

Comment: I made some changes and seems to work. 
`select calldate, src, clid, dst, disposition
from cdr
group by calldate, src
having sum(disposition = 'ANSWERED') = 0 order by calldate DESC limit 100`

Thank You My friend!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
from cdr t1
LEFT JOIN cdr t2 ON t1.SRC = t2.SRC  
      AND t1.Date = t2.Date
      AND t1.Disposition <> t2.Disposition
WHERE t1.disposition = 'NO ANSWER'
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.SRC
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```